Simplifications in Maple
I have this expression: $-22 - 4\sqrt{d - 1} + (4 + \sqrt{d - 1})\cdot d$ I've verified that it equals
$$ \left(\sqrt{d-1}-2\right) \left(\sqrt{d-1}+3\right)^{2} $$
My question is why when I write factor(-22 - 4sqrt(d - 1) + (4 + sqrt(d - 1))d) in Maple it doesn't give me the expression above. I need this kind of simplification because I have bigger expressions to get simplified.
Thanks for Reading.

Here is something you could try: do a change of variables and then track what's happening and translate it back to what you want. Here, you could've substituted $d - 1 = u^2$; your expression becomes just a polynomial - easily factorizable. I am rusty with Maple because I've been using Mathematica recently. Do note, though, that the "factor" command cannot possibly create all sorts of possible factorizations, especially when square roots and other uglier expressions are involved.

Is mathematica more suitable for that ?

Mathematica is a wizard at symbolic computation. At least, I could recommend trying it!

You can let Maple to do the substitutions into polynomial, e.g. E:=(d - 4)*sqrt(d - 1) + 4*d - 22; algsubs(k=sqrt(d-1),factor(algsubs(d-1=k^2,E)) assuming(k>0))
